# OpenGeo Explorer error publishing layers to geoserver

Tags: qgis, geoserver, boundless-suite

I want to use Opengeo Explorer to publish layers to geoserver but i am getting an error report. 
I create workspaces with no problems and i publish styles with no problems.
Can you pls help?

> Error while storing uploaded file::Read timed out Traceback (most recent call last): File > "C:/Users/tomis/.qgis2/python/plugins\opengeo\gui\explorer.py", line
>   118, in run command(*params) File
>   "C:/Users/tomis/.qgis2/python/plugins\opengeo\gui\confirm.py", line
>   18, in publishLayer catalog.publishLayer(layer, workspace, overwrite,
>   name) File
>   "C:/Users/tomis/.qgis2/python/plugins\opengeo\qgis\catalog.py", line
>   379, in publishLayer self.upload(layer, workspace, overwrite, title)
>   File "C:/Users/tomis/.qgis2/python/plugins\opengeo\qgis\catalog.py",
>   line 247, in upload self._uploadRest(layer, workspace, overwrite,
>   name) File
>   "C:/Users/tomis/.qgis2/python/plugins\opengeo\qgis\catalog.py", line
>   197, in _uploadRest overwrite=overwrite) File
>   "C:\Users\tomis.qgis2\python\plugins\opengeo\ext-libs\gsconfig-0.6.6-py2.7.egg\geoserver\catalog.py",
>   line 383, in create_featurestore raise UploadError(response)
>   UploadError: Could not save the layer Naxos_Points, there was an
>   upload error: Error while storing uploaded file::Read timed out